# Webpack 5.79.0 Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bootstrap-4

I new to Reactjs and Webpack. i'm trying to add boostrap to my react project from the book

> react projects: build advanced cross-platform projects with react and react native to become a professional developer, 2nd edition 2nd ed. edition

this is error message from localhost:8080
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> @charset "UTF-8";/*!
> |  * Bootstrap  v5.2.3 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
> |  * Copyright 2011-2022 The Bootstrap Authors

this is `index.js` where I import that file

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import List from './components/List';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

that file has a '@' at its start.
my `webpack.config.js` after I try several solutions

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                      loader: 'style-loader',
                    },
                    {
                      loader: 'css-loader',
                      options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                      },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                  // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                  'style-loader',
                  // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                  'css-loader',
                  // Compiles Sass to CSS
                  'sass-loader',
                ],
              },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin ({
            template: './public/index.html',
            filename: './index.html'
        }),
    ],
    };
```

my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "chapter_1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack": "^5.79.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.3"
  }
}
```